# How to delete a specific XML child node

Tags: xml, groovy

In Groovy, I want to delete a specific child node, but not all the child nodes.

Here is some example XML:

```
<A>
  <q>hello</q>
  <w>world</w>
  <e>again</e>
</A>
```

How do I delete the  node and it's content/attributes (if any)?

I've tried with the .replaceBody method on the  node, but child nodes aren't considered part of the body of the parent node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with XmlParser that produces `groovy.util.Node`

And there is a method remove in it. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html

```
def x = new XmlParser().parseText('''
<A>
  <q>hello</q>
  <w>world</w>
  <e>again</e>
</A>
''')

x.remove( x.w[0] )

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(x)
```